# ¿Como obtener los valores de un array de objetos y formar un array nuevo en VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola desde ya gracias por sus respuestas mi problema es el siguiente, tengo este array de objetos:

```
var rowsData = [
  {"id":1,"nombre":"darinel","edad":"2"},
  {"id":2,"nombre":"yair","edad":"24"},
  {"id":3,"nombre":"Daniel","edad":"24"},
  {"id":4,"nombre":"Saul","edad":"24"}
];
```

Quiero obtener de **rowsData** un array de arrays de la siguiente forma (Los valores de rowsData):

```
[
   [1, "darinel", "2"],
   [2, "yair", "24"],
   [3, "Daniel", "24"],
   [4, "Saul", "24"]
]
```

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
 columsActive() {
      this.rowsData.map((row) => this.testRows.push(Object.values(row)))
    }
```

Donde rowsData contiene mi array de objetos y testRows es un array vacio donde intento meter los valores con Object.values sin embargo esto no funciona al menos en vueJs y me devuelve la misma matriz de array de objetos en testRows.
De ante mano muchas gracias cualquier consejo o enlace a alguna doucumentación lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cons esto resolvi mi problema sabiendo que rowsData tiene la información que proporcione en la pregunta, tienes que crear una variable con un array vacio y en cada iteración del bucle foreach guardar cada valor con push.

```
columsActive() {
      Object.values(this.rowsData[0]).forEach((value) => {
        this.params.data.push(Object.values(value));
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tu problema esta en que tus variables no estan en tu funcion data de vue, es decir aqui.

```
data: () => ({
    rowsData: [
        { id: 1, nombre: "darinel", edad: "2" },
        { id: 2, nombre: "yair", edad: "24" },
        { id: 3, nombre: "Daniel", edad: "24" },
        { id: 4, nombre: "Saul", edad: "24" },
    ],
    testRows: [],
}),
```

por eso `var rowsData` te genera un error porque `this.rowsData` trata de acceder a esas variables de data

Comment: no se donde estas declarando `var rowsData` pero si fuera dentro de tu metodo `columsActive()` la logica seria asi `rowsData.map((row) => testRows.push(Object.values(row)));`